# Eclipse kepler maven Jars not copied to web/inf folder

Tags: eclipse, spring, hibernate, maven

```
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mindstix</groupId>
  <artifactId>SpringCrud</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>SpringCrud Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
   <packaging>war</packaging>
  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
       <scope>test</scope>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
          <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.3.Final</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.3.Final</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
   </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>SpringCrud</finalName>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                <target>${jdk.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>

</build>
```

This is my pom.xml. i am trying to runa simple spring maven hibernate example. But my jars are not getting copied to WEB-INF/lib/ folders.

i know this question is already answered, but i have defined packaging to war. Project deployment assemblies has maven dependencies setup and pointing to WEB-INF/lib folder but still when i do maven install through this pom this libs are not getting copied.

I am using Eclipse kepler and maven 3.2.1 
please help i tried everything even setting scope of dependencies to different types and no scope at all still my lib files are not getting copied

Comment: How did you create the project? maven-archetype-quickstart?

Comment: maven-archetype-webapp